# C#: How to Send a Key to a specific control?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I'm using a {DELETE} mnemonic but in some cases I want the default delete action to take place.  I thought I could do this via something like SendKeys.Send(target, keys) but I find no such option.

Specifically if a TextBox has focus I want the default processing to take place (otherwise I want custom processing).

Here's the code I'm struggling with:

```
    private void _menuEditDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_treeDocumentOutline.Focused)
        {
            DeleteNode();
        }
        else if (_gridAttributes.Focused)
        {
            DeleteSelectedRows();
        }
        else if (_gridAttributes.EditingControl != null && _gridAttributes.EditingControl.Focused)
        {
            // TODO: this is nuts...how to let the grid handle the key?  Losing ability to undo/redo this way
            var box = ((TextBox)_gridAttributes.EditingControl);
            var selectionStart = box.SelectionStart;
            var selectionEnd = box.SelectionStart + Math.Min(Math.Max(1, box.SelectionLength), box.Text.Length - box.SelectionStart);
            box.Text = box.Text.Substring(0, selectionStart) + box.Text.Substring(selectionEnd);
            box.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I have a Edit|Delete menu option with a Del mnemonic.  When a tree control or grid has focus I want to delete the node/row.  But if the grid is in edit mode and a cell has focus I want the underlying editbox to handle the delete.

Comment: If this in your app, or an external app?

Comment: My app..I have control of the source...I could, for instance, disable the "delete" menu command when entering edit mode.

Comment: That's how I do it. In fact I disable all shortcuts when in edit mode.